# Performance Recommendation for Node.js 'ws' and Redis PUB/SUB for Room Based Real-Time Communication

Tags: node.js, websocket, redis, chat, ws

I am working on a project that clients can join a room and communicate over WebSocket on NodeJS with `ws` module. Each WebSocket client has unique connection id and a room id. When new message comes from a client, first server gets its room id and loop over the connected `ws` clients to find who has the same room id. After it sends the message to each client has been found. For multiple node instances, I use Redis PUB/SUB for passing the messages to each instances. Because users in same room might be connected to the other instances. So, each node instances subscribes only one channel called 'signal'.

I have few question about performance:

1 - I don't want to loop over each client when each time new message comes. Thats why, I decided create Client object for each connection and store them in a Room object based on their room id. So, when new message comes, it will send it to the clients in the Room object. The Room objects also will be stored in  node. I will also keep room details in Redis. Do you think it is better than the first approach?

2 - Currently, each node instances subscribe only one channel called 'signal' . I want each client to subscribe channels according to their room id. Thanks to that, it will not check the room id every time when new message comes. But i am not sure what happens when there are thousands of rooms. Also, I am not sure about the Redis subscribe limits. Do you think, using channels for each room id makes performance better?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Which one did you use?

Comment: Didn't you tried some benchmark test with your current approach? how is it going?

Comment: I have used the second optıon by creating redis pub/sub channels for each room. Performance results was good enough.